# "Expected Declaration" Error on Delegate Function Call

Tags: swift3, xcode8

Xcode 8/Swift 3

Can anyone please tell me why I am getting this "expected declaration" error? The use of delegates answered my last question perfectly without getting this error.

Googling other "expected declaration" problems suggests function calls etc being in the wrong place but I don't think thats the case here - I have tried placing `delegate?.loadFirstView(viewFromModel: firstView)` in a separate function and then calling that function but I just get the same error. See the screenshot below:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

P.S: below is a screenshot of when my use of a delegate worked perfectly.

[image]

Third Screenshot with delegate call in a separate function:

[image]

Comment: ok, you are doing everything wrong, go to some tutorial and check step by step how to use delegates

Comment: Your response is very unhelpful. How do you think I got the delegate to work for my first question?

Comment: you are not calling your function. see that in working example you are calling update clock in timer, you cannot just put call in class, when it supposed to run? add button or start it after setting up a delegate

Comment: @Lu: Yes I have just noticed after pkc456 posted his code. I was forgetting that in the code that did work for me, the timer function was making the call to the delegate function and not me directly! To think that I've been looking and fiddling with this code now for several hours and have only just noticed such a stupid error! Thank you for your response though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the code (`delegate?.loadFirstView(viewFromModel : firstView)`) in the wrong place in the class. So move it to any function.

In your working [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNRh4.png), the code is written inside the `updateClock()`method, thus working without any error.

```
class modelClass{
            var delegate : LoadFirstViewProtocol?
            let firstView = "First view loaded"

            func testing()//Write here user defined method named
            {
                delegate?.loadFirstView(viewFromModel: firstView)
            }
        }
```

Comment: I tried that but am still getting the same error at the point  of calling the function. I'll put up a third screenshot.

Comment: @Rossco,  I have added the working code. Please check my [updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39837365/988169).

Comment: OK - I see what I was doing wrong now! Thank you pkc456!